# D3 Grouped Bar Chart From Arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm really having trouble with D3 and need some help changing my existing barchart to be a grouped barchart The barchart is being used within a tooltip and currently looks like:
[image]

Each colour represents a sector of industry (pink = retail, teal = groceries...etc).
I need to change the bar chart so that it compares the percentage change in each industry with the world average percentage change in this industry.

At the moment the bar chart is being created from an array of data. I also have an array with the world percentage values.

So imagine:

countryData = [10,-20,-30,-63,-23,20],
worldData = [23,-40,-23,-42,-23,40]

Where index 0 = retail sector, index 1 = grocery sector, etc.

I need to plot a grouped barchart comparing each sector to the world average (show the world average in red). This is a bit tricky to explain so I drew it for you (...excuse the shoddy drawing).

[image]

Please can someone help me change my existing tooltip?
Here's the current code. If you want to simulate the data values changing.
If you want to scrap my existing code that's fine.

```
 .on('mouseover', ({ properties }) => {
        // get county data
        const mobilityData = covid.data[properties[key]] || {};


      const {
        retailAverage,
        groceryAverage,
        parksAverage,
        transitAverage,
        workplaceAverage,
        residentialAverage,
      } = getAverage(covid1);



      let avgArray = [retailAverage, groceryAverage, parksAverage, transitAverage, workplaceAverage, retailAverage];
      let categoriesNames = ["Retail", "Grocery", "Parks", "Transit", "Workplaces", "Residential"];




        // create tooltip
        div = d3.select('body')
          .append('div')
          .attr('class', 'tooltip')
          .style('opacity', 0);

        div.html(properties[key]);

        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style('opacity', 0.9);

        // calculate bar graph data for tooltip
        const barData = [];

        Object.keys(mobilityData).forEach((industry) => {
          const stringMinusPercentage = mobilityData[industry].slice(0, -1);
          barData.push(+stringMinusPercentage); // changing it to an integer value, from string
        });

        //combine the two lists for the combined bar graph
        var combinedList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < barData.length; i++) {
          const stringMinusPercentage2 = +(avgArray[i].slice(0, -1));
          const object = {category: categoriesNames[i], country: barData[i], world: stringMinusPercentage2}
          combinedList.push(object); //Push object into list
        }
        console.log(combinedList);

        // barData = barData.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });
        // sort into ascending ^ keeping this in case we need it later
        const height2 = 220;
        const width2 = 250;
        const margin = {
          left: 50, right: 10, top: 20, bottom: 15,
        };

        // create bar chart svg
        const svgA = div.append('svg')
          .attr('height', height2)
          .attr('width', width2)
          .style('border', '1px solid')
          .append('g')
        // apply the margins:
          .attr('transform', `translate(${[`${margin.left},${margin.top}`]})`);

        const barWidth = 30; // Width of the bars

        // plot area is height - vertical margins.
        const chartHeight = height2 - margin.top - margin.left;

        // set the scale:
        const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([-100, 100])
          .range([chartHeight, 0]);

        // draw some rectangles:
        svgA
          .selectAll('rect')
          .data(barData)
          .enter()
          .append('rect')
          .attr('x', (d, i) => i * barWidth)
          .attr('y', (d) => {
            if (d < 0) {
              return yScale(0); // if the value is under zero, the top of the bar is at yScale(0);
            }

            return yScale(d); // otherwise the rectangle top is above yScale(0) at yScale(d);
          })
          .attr('height', (d) => Math.abs(yScale(0) - yScale(d))) // the height of the rectangle is the difference between the scale value and yScale(0);
          .attr('width', barWidth)
          .style('fill', (d, i) => colours[i % 6]) // colour the bars depending on index
          .style('stroke', 'black')
          .style('stroke-width', '1px');

        // Labelling the Y axis
        const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
        svgA.append('text')
          .attr('class', 'y label')
          .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
          .attr('x', -15)
          .attr('y', -25)
          .attr('dy', '-.75em')
          .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
          .text('Percentage Change (%)');

        svgA.append('g')
          .call(yAxis);
      })
      .on('mouseout', () => {
        div.style('opacity', 0);
        div.remove();
      })
      .on('mousemove', () => div
        .style('top', `${d3.event.pageY - 140}px`)
        .style('left', `${d3.event.pageX + 15}px`));

    svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(25,25)')
      .call(colorLegend, {
        colorScale,
        circleRadius: 10,
        spacing: 30,
        textOffset: 20,
      });

  };

  drawMap(svg1, geoJson1, geoPath1, covid1, key1, 'impact1');
  drawMap(svg2, geoJson2, geoPath2, covid2, key2, 'impact2');
};
```

Comment: can you upload that in a fiddle online?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In short I would suggest you to use two Band Scales for x axis. I've attached a code snippet showing the solution.
Enjoy ;)

```js
//Assuming the following data final format
var finalData = [
  { 
    "groupKey": "Retail",
    "sectorValue": 70,
    "worldValue": 60
  },
  { 
    "groupKey": "Grocery",
    "sectorValue": 90,
    "worldValue": 90
  },
  { 
    "groupKey": "other",
    "sectorValue": -20,
    "worldValue": 30
  }
];
var colorRange = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#00BCD4", "#FFC400", "#ECEFF1"]);
var subGroupKeys = ["sectorValue", "worldValue"];

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var container = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
// The scale spacing the groups, your "sectors":
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(finalData.map(d => d.groupKey))
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.1);

// The scale for spacing each group's bar, your "sector bar":
var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(subGroupKeys)
    .rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()])
    .padding(0.05);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-100, 100])
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);
        
//and then you will need to append both, groups and bars
var groups = container.append('g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(finalData, d => d.groupKey)
  .join("g")
  .attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + x0(d.groupKey) + ",0)");

//define groups bars, one per sub group 
var bars = groups
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(d => subGroupKeys.map(key => ({ key, value: d[key], groupKey: d.groupKey })), (d) => "" + d.groupKey + "_" + d.key)
  .join("rect")
  .attr("fill", d => colorRange(d.key))
  .attr("x", d => x1(d.key))
  .attr("width", (d) => x1.bandwidth())
  .attr('y', (d) => Math.min(yScale(0), yScale(d.value)))
  .attr('height', (d) => Math.abs(yScale(0) - yScale(d.value)));

//append x axis
container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

//append y axis
container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 2)
    .attr("y", yScale(yScale.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
    .attr("dy", "0.32em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text("Values");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<svg width="600" height="400"></svg>
```